# concatenate every n rows into one row pandas

Tags: pandas, concatenation

I have:

```
pd.DataFrame({'col':['one','fish','two','fish','left','foot','right','foot']})
    col
0   one
1   fish
2   two
3   fish
4   left
5   foot
6   right
7   foot
```

I want to concatenate every n rows (here every 4) and form a new dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame({'col':['one fish two fish','left foot right foot']})
    col
0   one fish two fish
1   left foot right foot
```

I am using Python and pandas

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If there is default `RangeIndex` then use integer division with aggregate `join`:

```
print (df.groupby(df.index // 4).agg(' '.join))
#for not RangeIndex create helper array
#print (df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 4).agg(' '.join))
                    col
0     one fish two fish
1  left foot right foot
```

If want specify column `col`:

```
print (df.groupby(df.index // 4)['col'].agg(' '.join).to_frame())
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `groupby`:

```
df['col'].groupby(np.repeat(np.arange(len(df)), 4)[:len(df)]).agg(' '.join)
```

Output:

```
0       one fish two fish
1    left foot right foot
Name: col, dtype: object
```